# the use of the blocking functions together with signals (QTcpSocket)

Tags: c++, qt

I write a `AsyncSocket` that use `QTcpSocket` to work with some servers. They (servers) were wrote long time ago and I have no ability to change them.

So, **the problem is** the lack of `readyRead` signal if server could not recognize the message (because it did nothing with `default` message type). I think it is the server problem, because it should response anyway... but it is not my own code and I have to use it like it is.

I thought to use `QAbstractSocket::waitForReadyRead(int msecs)` but found in [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#details) (the end of the 'details' section):

> **Note**: We discourage the use of the blocking functions together with
>   signals. One of the two possibilities should be used.

So, I am a bit confused why I should not use  blocking method like this:

```
void AsyncSocket::send(const QByteArray &msg)
{
    socket->write(msg);

    if (!socket->waitForReadyRead(msecs))
        qDebug() << "Warning! ReadyRead were not emitted";
}
```

---

The server works like this:

```
switch(received_msg.type)
{
    case TYPE_ONE: // do smth
        break;

    case TYPE_TWO: // do smth
        break;

    case TYPE_N:   // do smth
        break;

    default: 
        // do NOTHING
}
```

My class:

```
class AsyncSocket
{
public:
    void connectToHost(const QString &host, qint16 port);
    void send(const QByteArray &msg);
    void disconnectFromHost();

    // other public members

public slots:
    void connected();
    void readyRead();
};
```

---

**UPDATE**: It can be useful to catch missing `readyRead` signals to organize queue of messages using `AsyncSocket`

Comment: I am not shure what you're asking. So your problem is that the server does not reply for certain messages and you want to detect when that happens?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Qt doc says it is not good idea to use block methods. But it is not clear what the alternative is.

Comment: Then you have 2 options. Either you do wait as described above (but this will block your application and is generally not recommended) or you use `QTimer` to trigger a timeout if to much time passes before readyRead is emitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem following the advice of *Felix* about `QTimer` like this:

```
class AsyncSocket
{
public:
    void connectToHost(const QString &host, qint16 port);
    void send(const QByteArray &msg);
    void disconnectFromHost();

    // other public members
signals:
    void dataReady(const QByteArray &data);

public slots:
    void connected();
    void readyRead();

private slots:
    // I created the timer timeout signal here connected in AsyncSocket constructor
    void missRead(); 
private:
    QTimer *timer; // and timer pointer here allocated in constructor also
};
```

I start the timer when user sends a message:

```
bool AsyncSocket::send(const QByteArray &msg, int responseSize)
{
    // successfull sending code here

    timer->start(msecs);
    return true;
}
```

And I use signals to handle cases of reading like this:

```
void AsyncSocket::readyRead() // successfull reading
{
    if (socket->bytesAvailable() == responseSize) // buffer has all data
    {
        timer->stop();
        emit (dataReady(socket->readAll()));
        // reset device, clear buffer, etc.
    }
}

void AsyncSocket::missRead() // server stoped to reply
{
    timer->stop();
    emit(dataReady(QByteArray()));
    // reset device, clear buffer, etc.
}
```